# How do I route requests for an entire subnet over a VPN connection on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have an Ubuntu machine connected to a VPN, with the IP address `172.16.1.250`.  I want to tunnel all the requests for `172.16.1.*` through the VPN, but nothing else.  If I try to use `sudo route -net add 172.16.1.0/24 dev ppp0`, I get the error message:

```
netmask 00000fff doesn't make sense with host route
```

However, simply adding a route for one address on that subnet works.  What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Why wouldn't a route to the remote network already exist in the routing table when the VPN is connected? Have you looked at the routing table while the VPN is connected?

Answer (score 3):

You have the arguments swapped around, the correct syntax is: `sudo route add -net 172.16.1.0/24 dev ppp0`

Comment: Did this answer solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issues because I was misusing `-n` instead `-net`.

This works:

```
sudo route add -net 172.19.0.0/16 dev ppp0
```

This **do NOT work**:

```
$ sudo route add -n 172.19.0.0/16 dev ppp0
route: netmask 0000ffff doesn't make sense with host route
Usage: inet_route [-vF] del {-host|-net} Target[/prefix] [gw Gw] [metric M] [[dev] If]
       inet_route [-vF] add {-host|-net} Target[/prefix] [gw Gw] [metric M]
                              [netmask N] [mss Mss] [window W] [irtt I]
                              [mod] [dyn] [reinstate] [[dev] If]
       inet_route [-vF] add {-host|-net} Target[/prefix] [metric M] reject
       inet_route [-FC] flush      NOT supported
```

`man route` states:

```
   -n     show  numerical  addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host names. This is useful if you are trying to determine why the route to
          your nameserver has vanished.
...
   -net   the target is a network.
```